# Oracle materialized view add new data but without update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a join request and the data can change during the day and from date to date (deleted rows), so I want to keep certain data by picking them and save them elsewhere the next day from 3 months.

Usually, I would do a materialized view (for performances / do not touch the production tables) and refresh it every night /or on logs, but the issue here is that I want to be able to ADD the new data from yesterday and do not update the whole mview (data will be deleted from the mview then) and say: what is older than 3 months can be deleted.

How can I do this? Maybe I'm totally wrong thinking about mview and the only way is with dbms_scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Use your own table, then. Schedule a job (using `dbms_scheduler` you mentioned) which will

- insert new rows (dated *yesterday*)
- delete rows older than 3 months

Properly index it so that you'd be able to fetch "archive" data faster than without an index. Don't forget to regularly gather statistics on both table and index(es).

Comment: Thank you, that confirm what I thought !